# Error when baking FlipFluid simulation when using add-on curve spiral as a force field

Tags: physics

Error message appears when trying to bake a curve force field. The curve is from the "Add curve : Extra objects" add-on. Is it because I'm using the free demo version of FlipFluids?

[image]

Here is the file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/10lZzyx8psbADO4PqFjNc36FKIGEKpET1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in flip fluids you can read about the demo restrictions. I would assume: no, it is not a restriction. If it would be, i would expect an error message for this. Maybe the better place for asking is in github for flipfluids and create an issue. Or short: seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Yep, just got a reply from a dev and apparently it was a bug which will be fixed by the 20th